# How to add 8 hours to my datetime in SQLite without updating it?

Tags: sqlite, datetime

How to add 8 hours to my datetime in SQLite without updating it? Like it will be the timestamp when written to my database

This is the code for my `dump.sql`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS feed (
feed_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
feed TEXT,
user_id_fk INTEGER,
created DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

I wanted to add 8hrs because if I use the `timeago` plugin it will show `8hrs ago` even though I just added it
This is how I get the data

```
getAllFeeds(user_id_fk) {
  let data = [user_id_fk]
  return this.database.executeSql("SELECT * FROM feed WHERE (user_id_fk) = (?) ORDER BY feed_id DESC", data).then((data) => {
    let feeds = [];
    if (data.rows.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
        feeds.push({ feed_id: data.rows.item(i).feed_id, feed: data.rows.item(i).feed, user_id_fk: data.rows.item(i).user_id_fk, created: data.rows.item(i).created });
      }
    }
    return feeds;
  }, err => {
    console.log('Error: ', err);
    return [];
  });
}
```

Comment: Why not handle this before it goes into the DB? Or set the system clock so SQLite knows to use the correct time zone?

Comment: How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT DATETIME(created, '+8 hours') as `add8hours` FROM feed WHERE (user_id_fk) = (?) ORDER BY feed_id DESC;
```

Comment: Hi @Ramgy please see my edit. I hope you can help me insert you code to mine

Comment: @JohnDoe yes it works if you add DATETIME(datetimecolumn, '+8 hours') for example createtime = 10:30AM +8 hours = 6:30PM

Comment: I already got this `"SELECT * FROM feed WHERE (user_id_fk) = (?) ORDER BY feed_id DESC"` how can I insert it to the code?

Comment: used `SELECT DATETIME(datetimecolumn, '+8 hours'),.....  FROM feed WHERE..` instead of  `* ` to get the correct answer

Comment: don't used `SELECT * FROM table`

Comment: now it only shows the time and the feeds are missing. I marked your answer as accepted answer because it's working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153730/discussion-between-ramgy-borja-and-john-doe).

Comment: feeds is a column or a table?